# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM after upgrading node 16=>20 and other libraries

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to upgrade node from version 16 => 20
I also decided to try and upgrade some other libraries altogether
I tried starting my backend after the upgrades

```
% yarn run dev
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --transpileOnly --files src/index.ts`
```

soon followed by

```
/Users/.../backend/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:851
            return old(m, filename);
                   ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/.../backend/node_modules/file-type/index.js from /Users/.../backend/src/feature-core/upload-file.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/.../backend/src/feature-core/upload-file.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/.../backend/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:851:20)
```

I am not sure what needs to be updated or how, I tried making some changes following some github issues but could't find a solution.

### Update

This is where the error takes place:

```
import { protectedProcedure } from '../trpc/initialize'
import { randomString } from '../utils/rand'
import { uploadFile as uploadFileToS3 } from '../lib/s3'
import { TRPCError } from '@trpc/server'
import { fileTypeFromBuffer } from 'file-type'

export const uploadFileBase64 = protectedProcedure.input(z.object({ body: z.string() })).mutation(async ({ input }) => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(input.body, 'base64')
  const fileType = await fileTypeFromBuffer(buffer)

  if (fileType === undefined) {
    throw new TRPCError({ code: 'BAD_REQUEST', message: 'ファイルの種類を判定できませんでした' })
  }

  const key = `${randomString()}.${fileType.ext}`
  await uploadFileToS3({
    key,
    body: buffer,
    contentType: fileType.mime,
  })

  return { key: '' }
})
```

I am not using require, neither here nor in any other file, so according to the answers I am guessing I need to add `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`.
However after adding that I got this error instead:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/.../backend/src/index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:91:20)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:263:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:179:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:203:17)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:34)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:141:17) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So I am guessing there is still something I am missing.

Comment: Your question has been answered below you’re just not understanding. Your project compiles down to CJS whether you explicitly write require expressions or not. Pay attention to this part `node_modules/file-type/index.js` which is referencing an ESM-only package. That is the cause of your issue. If your project already uses `type: module` you can try moduleResolution of nodenext.

Comment: @morganney I shared the file giving the error instead of part of the code. I am probably just missing something, but as you can see I am not using ```require()```, and it is not that I am using ```type: module```, but using it just gave me another error. What other changes do i need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Answer

```
const fileTypes = await eval("import('file-type')")
```

putting this inside an async function should do the trick

### Explanation

As explained by @monim the library `file-type` became **ESM-only package** after an upgrade, which required me to add `"type": "module"` and change all my imports to ESM format.

Did I want to change to ESM?
No, only one library had become ESM-only, and inside a pretty large directory I would rather keep the changes I make minimal.
So as suggested by @Evert I tried using `await import` inside an async function.
This worked perfectly, and everything ran smoothly except tslint which gave me this error:

```
error TS1323: Dynamic imports are only supported when the '--module' flag is set to 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.
```

And after a quick search I found out that changing the code to `eval('await import())` could fix the tslint error message.
If you are not using tslint this should work fine as well:

```
const fileTypes = await import ('file-type')
```

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs because a package you are importing has been converted to an **ESM-only package** (ECMAScript modules ), which means that the package cannot be imported with require() anymore. so as you said you upgraded some libraries first you have to check if they no longer support ESM .

to solve this error use **imports/exports** instead of **require()** .

don't forget to add `"type": "module"` to your **package.json** file: .

Comment: Thanks but I double checked my code and I am positive I don't have files using ```require()``` and adding ```"type": "module"``` throws ```TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"``` instead. Are there any other changes I need to make?

Comment: @TheBlindHawk even though you might use `import` in typescript, it probably still got compiled to commonjs. There's lots of guides around switching to ESM, but a bg thing is you need to specify all extensions as `.js` not `.ts` when importing (yes even when it's not a .js file in the same directory)

Comment: @Evert I see, so if I switch to ESM (by adding ```type: module```), I need to change all the imports to ```.js```, but since it is probably only 1 library that is requesting ESM only after the upgrade, would the best course of action be just to downgrade it? I'd rather not have to change every import in a large directory just because of one lib.

Comment: @TheBlindHawk, no it's possible to import ESM libraries into commonjs scripts using the `await import(...')` syntax. this means you can only import inside an async function.

Comment: @Evert thank you!! I changed the import to ```const fileTypes = await import ('file-type'); const fileTypeFromBuffer = fileTypes.fileTypeFromBuffer``` inside the async function and it worked!